# Why i move to another page after select value from 'select' form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I want to create text filed according to the number that user select from a 'select' form.
when i select some value, i move to another page.
I want that the select form will change to text filed.

Thanks.

```
<form name="dummyForm">
<select name="selectBox" onchange="getSelectedvalue()">
<option value="1">1</option>  
<option value="2">2</option>  
<option value="3">3</option> 
<option value="4">4</option> 
<option value="5">5</option>  
<option value="6">6</option>  
<option value="7">7</option>  
<option value="8">8</option>  
<option value="9">9</option>  
<option value="10">10</option>
</select >
</form>



    function getSelectedvalue() {
        var getSelectedIndex = document.dummyForm.selectBox.selectedIndex;
        var getSelectedOptionText = document.dummyForm.selectBox[getSelectedIndex].text;
        document.write("<form name='rsvp' method='get' action='CheckUsername.java'>");
        for (i = 0; i < getSelectedOptionText; i++) {
            document.write(" שם פרטי : <input type='text' name='name'>");
            document.write("<br>");
        }
        document.write("<input type='submit' name='submit1' value='submit'>");
        document.write("</form>");
    }


    </script>
```

Comment: You're not moving to another page, but document.write overwrites the current page.

Comment: you are not moving to another page you are rewriting the current one, do not use document.write for this reason. Use the DOM api instead.